# Where are the JAXB schemas published?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

The JAXB 1.0 and JAXB 2.0 schemas are supposed to be available from the [Bindings Schema for JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/jaxb/index.html) site. Unfortunately, it was last updated in 2005 and all of the links are broken. What is the official location of the schemas? There should be some authoritative source for v1.0, 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JAXB XML Schemas**

[JAXB 1.0 XML Schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_1_0.xsd)

[JAXB 2.0 XML Schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd)

It seems that there is no version 2.2 of the schema. The most recent would be 2.1.

And an [old post from the java.net](https://www.java.net/node/697511) forums (now defunct) stated:

> I don't think it has been published (we should fix that), but if you have a jaxb-xjc jar file, you can find it inside the jar.

The relevant files in `jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar` are:

```
com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd
com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/xjc.xsd
com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/xs.xsd
```

From the source repository: [Binding](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/schemas/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd), [XJC](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/schemas/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/xjc.xsd) and [XS](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/schemas/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/xs.xsd) schemas.

**Note:** In addition to the original 1.0 and 2.0 schema links from 2005 being broken at least twice (changed from *sun.com* to *oracle.com*, then moving into Oracle's *technetwork*), the locations for the 2.1 schemas changed at least four more times between 2015 and 2018 due to a switch from `http` to `https` on *java.net*, the closure of *java.net*, migration of the code base to GitHub, and refactoring to move the schemas from `src/main/java` to `src/main/schemas`.