# Convention for storing XSD file in a Java Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd

What is the conventional folder for storing `.xsd` files in a Java Eclipse project? For example, `.jars` are kept in `/lib`. Where would an `.xsd` file be stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally put my XML schemas in `/src/main/resources/XSD` but as you can see from the [JAXB project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30947169/2074605), they are often placed in deep source folders with the most relevant package.